Changing the FOV in iOS ARkit
In the latest generation iPad pro (M4), Apple changed the front facing camera to an Ultrawide camera (the 0.5x that iPhones have), rather than a 'regular' camera. All Apple applications seem to be cropping the camera feed to the old FOV, and this cropped region can be adjusted on the fly to follow you to always be in camera if you move around during a video call (=Center Stage).
Now unfortunately with the default ARFaceTrackingConfiguration, you get the full wide angle camera feed, which is not ideal for face tracking (you have to bring the device a lot closer to your face to get a similar picture as on older models).
How can you crop the FOV of the AR session? I have tried setting the FieldOfView property of the ScienView's camera object but that doesn't have any effect.
Here is a minimal example:
import SwiftUI
import ARKit

struct FaceTrackingView1: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> FaceTrackingViewController1 {
        return FaceTrackingViewController1()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: FaceTrackingViewController1, context: Context) {
    }
}

class FaceTrackingViewController1: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {
    var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView = ARSCNView(frame: view.bounds)
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true
        view.addSubview(sceneView)

        let config = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(config)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        guard anchor is ARFaceAnchor else { return nil }

        let faceGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: sceneView.device!)!
        let faceNode = SCNNode(geometry: faceGeometry)
        faceNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.fillMode = .lines // Makes it a wireframe mesh

        return faceNode
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor,
              let faceGeometry = node.geometry as? ARSCNFaceGeometry else { return }

        faceGeometry.update(from: faceAnchor.geometry)
    }
}

And the contentView:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isFaceTrackingActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Face mesh tracking demo")
                .font(.title)
                .padding()
            
            // Button directly on the main screen
            Button(action: {
                isFaceTrackingActive.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Start Face Tracking")
                    .font(.title2)
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isFaceTrackingActive) {
                FaceTrackingView1()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

To be clear I am not looking to get Center Stage functionality that automatically tracks the user, I just want a fixed cropped FOV that is comparable to older iPads.
